# how to speed up dataframe analysis

Tags: python, performance, pandas

I'm looping through a DataFrame of 200k rows. It's doing what I want but it takes hours. I'm not very sophisticated when it comes to all the ways you can join and manipulate DataFrames so I wonder if I'm doing this in a very inefficient way. It's quite simple, here's the code:

```
three_yr_gaps = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    three_yr_gaps.append(df[(df['GROUP_ID'] == row['GROUP_ID']) &
                            (df['BEG_DATE'] >= row['THREE_YEAR_AGO']) &
                            (df['END_DATE'] <= row['BEG_DATE'])]['GAP'].sum() + row['GAP'])
df['GAP_THREE'] = three_yr_gaps
```

The DF has a column called `GAP` that holds an integer value. the logic I'm employing to sum this number up is:

for each row get these columns from the dataframe:

1. those that match on the group id, and...
2. those that have a beginning date within the last 3 years of this rows start date, and...
3. those that have an ending date before this row's beginning date.

sum up those rows `GAP` number and add this row's `GAP` number then append those to a list of indexes.

So is there a faster way to introduce this logic into some kind of automatic merge or join that could speed up this process?

PS.

I was asked for some clarification on input and output, so here's a constructed dataset to play with:

```
from dateutil import parser
df = pd.DataFrame(  columns = ['ID_NBR','GROUP_ID','BEG_DATE','END_DATE','THREE_YEAR_AGO','GAP'],
                    data = [['09','185',parser.parse('2008-08-13'),parser.parse('2009-07-01'),parser.parse('2005-08-13'),44],
                            ['10','185',parser.parse('2009-08-04'),parser.parse('2010-01-18'),parser.parse('2006-08-04'),35],
                            ['11','185',parser.parse('2010-01-18'),parser.parse('2011-01-18'),parser.parse('2007-01-18'),0],
                            ['12','185',parser.parse('2014-09-04'),parser.parse('2015-09-04'),parser.parse('2011-09-04'),0]])
```

and here's what I wrote at the top of the script, may help:

> The purpose of this script is to extract gaps counts over the
>   last 3 year period. It uses gaps.sql as its source extract. this query
>   returns a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
 ID_NBR  GROUP_ID  BEG_DATE    END_DATE    THREE_YEAR_AGO  GAP
 09      185       2008-08-13  2009-07-01  2005-08-13      44
 10      185       2009-08-04  2010-01-18  2006-08-04      35
 11      185       2010-01-18  2011-01-18  2007-01-18      0
 12      185       2014-09-04  2015-09-04  2011-09-04      0
```

> The python code then looks back at the previous 3 years (those
>   previous rows that have the same GROUP_ID but whose effective dates
>   come after their own THIRD_YEAR_AGO and whose end date come before
>   their own beginning date). Those rows are added up and a new column is
>   made called GAP_THREE.  What remains is this:

```
 ID_NBR  GROUP_ID  BEG_DATE    END_DATE    THREE_YEAR_AGO  GAP  GAP_THREE
 09      185       2008-08-13  2009-07-01  2005-08-13      44   44
 10      185       2009-08-04  2010-01-18  2006-08-04      35   79
 11      185       2010-01-18  2011-01-18  2007-01-18      0    79
 12      185       2014-09-04  2015-09-04  2011-09-04      0    0
```

> you'll notice that row id_nbr 11  has a 79 value in the last 3 years but id_nbr 12 has 0 because the last gap was 35 in 2009 which is more than 3 years before 12's beginning date of 2014

Comment: Can you provide some input data (say 20 rows) and desired output? This will help us test & benchmark consistently.

Comment: @jpp yes, sorry, I've included an example. The problem is generalizable though - how do you extract a defined list of rows defined by some logical criteria for each row in the data frame efficiently? I just don't know the best pattern.

Comment: Strangely enough, I found that breaking out the logic into separate steps, getting subsequently closer to the final set I want is performing faster, like two or three times faster.
`temp=df[df['GROUP_ID']==row['GROUP_ID']]   ;    
temp=temp[temp['BEG_DATE']>=row['THIRD_YEAR_AGO']]   ;   
temp=temp[temp['END_DATE']<=row['BEG_DATE']]   ;   
add=temp['GAP'].sum()+row['GAP']   ;   
cov.append(add)`

Comment: If `GROUP_ID=185` had another row with begin date of 2012-01-01 
and `GAP=1` would it's `GAP_THREE` value be 36?

Comment: @ALollz yes because three years before 2012-01-01 is before 2009-08-04